# TCPDF image resize

Tags: php, pdf, image-resizing, tcpdf

I want to crate pdf with the leatest TCPDF.
I have an LC6 landscape document (152mm × 109mm). I put an image to the page, and set the image parameters like this:

```
$pdf->Image($image, 0, 0, 152, 0, 'PNG', '', '', true, 300);
```

The pdf file is empty. But, when I change 152 to 151, the image is appear in the pdf file, but smaller then the document.
Why disappear the image when it has enough space?
My picture is 1795×1287px but its doesn't matter because I want to resize it.
**Update:**
This problem doesn't occur with every picture, in other picture is appear correctly in pdf. The two images has same dpi and same resolution. Could be the source of problem the transparency?

Comment: Probably it's something like this; `1795/152 = 11.809210526`. It looks like the end value gets rounded down, thus `11.8`. And then `1287/11.8 = 109.06779661`, resulting in a "bleed". It might be the case that the PDF creator can't cut off the images and just discards those that don't fit on the canvas. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: it seems unfortunately no, because I increase the document size to `110mm` and still doesn't appear the image. But thanks, it was good idea. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved.
The cache folder must be writeable. Unfortunately I have not found this information in the documentation, I have found it in the source code, in some images parser method's comment.

Comment: hi @mrrp I have similar problem, How do you make that image bigger can you explain it a lil bit in detail?

Comment: Which cache folder you are indicating ? Can you specify path?

Comment: Sorry but is missed the questions. As far as I remember in the tcpdf_config file you have a K_PATH_CACHE constant. This should be writeable.